# Current map the CIDR values wrong in subnet creation

Tags: azure, kubernetes, terraform, subnet, cidr

I have an Azure question. I use terraform in the Azure Cloud service. I try to start up 2 AKS cluster there. But I always get an error that my CIDR settings are wrong.

I use in Cluster one:

```
resource "azurerm_subnet" "cluster1-node-pool-subnet" {

  name                 = "cluster1-node-pool-subnet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_virtual_network.cluster-vnet.resource_group_name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.cluster-vnet.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.1.0/19"]

}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "cluster1-execution-nodes-subnet" {

  name                 = "cluster1-execution-nodes-subnet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_virtual_network.cluster-vnet.resource_group_name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.cluster-vnet.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.33.0/19"]

}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "cluster1-gpu-nodes-subnet" {
  count                = var.gpuNodePool ? 1 : 0
  name                 = "execution-nodes-subnet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_virtual_network.cluster-vnet.resource_group_name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.cluster-vnet.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.48.0/20"]

}

network_profile {
  network_plugin     = "azure"
  service_cidr       = "10.0.65.0/19"  
  dns_service_ip     = "10.0.65.10"    
  docker_bridge_cidr = "172.17.0.1/16" 
}
```

and in Cluster two:

```
resource "azurerm_subnet" "default-node-pool-subnet" {

  name                 = "default-node-pool-subnet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_virtual_network.cluster-vnet.resource_group_name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.cluster-vnet.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.0.0/19"]

}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "execution-nodes-subnet" {

  name                 = "execution-nodes-subnet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_virtual_network.cluster-vnet.resource_group_name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.cluster-vnet.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.32.0/19"]

}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "gpu-nodes-subnet" {
  count                = var.gpuNodePool ? 1 : 0
  name                 = "execution-nodes-subnet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_virtual_network.cluster-vnet.resource_group_name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.cluster-vnet.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.48.0/20"]
}

network_profile {
  network_plugin     = "azure"
  service_cidr       = "10.0.64.0/19"
  dns_service_ip     = "10.0.64.10"
  docker_bridge_cidr = "172.17.0.1/16"
}
```

Azur now tell me that the prefix is wrong.

```
│ Error: creating Subnet: (Name "cluster1-node-pool-subnet" / Virtual Network Name "cluster-vnet" / Resource Group "cluster-infra-network"): network.SubnetsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="InvalidCIDRNotation" Message="The address prefix 10.0.1.0/19 in resource /subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroupscluster-infra-network/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/cluster-vnet/subnets/cluster1-node-pool-subnet has an invalid CIDR notation. For the given prefix length, the address prefix should be 10.0.0.0/19." Details=[]
│
│   with azurerm_subnet.cluster1-node-pool-subnet,
│   on k8s-rtc.tf line 7, in resource "azurerm_subnet" "cluster1-node-pool-subnet":
│    7: resource "azurerm_subnet" "cluster1-node-pool-subnet" {
│
╵
╷
│ Error: creating Subnet: (Name "cluster1-execution-nodes-subnet" / Virtual Network Name "cluster-vnet" / Resource Group "cluster-infra-network"): network.SubnetsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="InvalidCIDRNotation" Message="The address prefix 10.0.33.0/19 in resource /subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/cluster-infra-network/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/cluster-vnet/subnets/cluster1-execution-nodes-subnet has an invalid CIDR notation. For the given prefix length, the address prefix should be 10.0.32.0/19." Details=[]
│
│   with azurerm_subnet.cluster1-execution-nodes-subnet,
│   on k8s-rtc.tf line 14, in resource "azurerm_subnet" "cluster1-execution-nodes-subnet":
│   14: resource "azurerm_subnet" "cluster1-execution-nodes-subnet" {
```

In my mind the CIDR and prefix are valid. any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately, they are not, there's an overlap. Which octet you want to use? Third, fourth?

Comment: As sample from 0000 1010 | 0000 0000 | 0000 0000 | 0000 0000 I want to use the last  | 0000 0000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are basically two issues in your subnet definitions:

1. Azure tells you that you are using invalid CIDR notations. E.g. in case of `cluster1-node-pool-subnet` you are specifying in address prefix `["10.0.1.0/19"]`. While `10.0.1.0/19` is a valid IP address, it belongs to the subnet `10.0.0.0/19` and Azure insists that you need to specify the address prefix based on the network address of the subnet.

   The same applies to e.g. `10.0.33.0/19` which belongs to the subnet `10.0.32.0/19`.
2. This unveils the second issue, which Azure will report to you once the first is fixed: In both subnets you are using the same address prefixes in the subnets you are defining. To overcome this you could use e.g. `["10.0.0.0/19"]` for `cluster1-node-pool-subnet` and `["10.1.0.0/19"]` for `default-node-pool-subnet` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are being asked to assign the network address, and you are instead assigning a host address. Let me show you graphically what is going wrong. (images are from a iphone app I am currently working on and is not released.)

[image: Shows 10.0.1.0/19 as a host address]

[image: Shows 10.0.33.0/19 as a host address]

[image: Shows 10.0.48.0/19 a another host address in the same subnet as the 10.0.33.0/19 host]